# Axiom Problems (Intro to Computer Logic)

Tags: logic, axioms, formal-proofs

> "Show that—or prove that—$ \Gamma \vdash A $" means "write a $ \Gamma $-proof that establishes $ A $". The proof can be Equational or Hilbert-style.
>
> Show that $ A \equiv C \vdash A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow C) $

I am not sure if I did this right..

Proving RHS:

$$ \begin{align}
     A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow C) &\ \ \langle \mbox{Implication, properties of} \rightarrow \rangle
\\   A → (B \lor C) &\ \ \langle \mbox{Implication, properties of} \rightarrow \rangle
\\   A → (C) &\ \ \langle \mbox{Implication, properties of} \rightarrow \rangle
\\   A \lor C &\ \ \langle \mbox{Golden Rule, Properties of } \ \lor \rangle
\\   A \equiv C &, 
   \end{align}
$$

Therefore I proved RHS to LHS

#### List of Axioms

Associativity of $ \equiv $

- $ ((A \equiv B) \equiv C) \equiv (A \equiv (B \equiv C)) $ (1)

Symmetry of $ \equiv $

- $ (A \equiv B) \equiv (B \equiv A) $ (2)

Properties of $ \bot $, $ \top $

- $ \top \equiv \bot \equiv \bot $ (3)

Properties of $ \neg $

- $ \neg A \equiv A \equiv \bot $ (4)

Properties of $ \lor $

- $ (A \lor B) \lor C \equiv A \lor (B \lor C) $ (5)
- $ A \lor B \equiv B \lor A $ (6)
- $ A \lor A \equiv A $ (7)
- $ A \lor (B \equiv C) \equiv A \lor B \equiv A \lor C $ (8)
- $ A \lor \neg A $ (9)

Properties of $ \land $

- Golden Rule: $ A \land B \equiv A \equiv B \equiv A \lor B $ (10)

Properties of $ \rightarrow $

- Implication: $ A \rightarrow B \equiv A \lor B \equiv B $ (11)

Comment: You want LHS to RHS, don't you?

Comment: In proving RHS, you have derived from $A \to (B \to C)$ the formula $A \to (B \lor C)$. Whit $A$ true and $B,C$ FALSE we have that the premise is TRUE while the conclusion is FALSE. Thus, the inference is wrong.

Comment: I was just following the rules of the properties so I am not sure if it is FALSE

Comment: But the Implication rule does not mean that $A \to B$ is equiv to $A \lor B$: the two are not; neither that $A \lor B$ is equiv to $B$: the two are not.

Comment: The rule says that $A \to B$ is equiv to $(A \lor B) \equiv B$.

Comment: The rule says also that $(A \to B) \equiv (A \lor B)$ is equiv to $B$.

Comment: You are right, what I did was completely wrong.

Comment: So anyone know how to prove it using the correct rule implication?

Answer (score 1):

We cannot prove it only by "chain-of-equivalences", because the conclusion is implied by the premise but it is not equivalent to it.

Thus we need rules of inference, e.g. *Equanimity* :

> $\dfrac {A, A \equiv C} {C}$

In addition, we can use two meta-theorems :

> *Hypothesis Strengthening* : If $\Gamma \vdash A$ and $\Gamma \subseteq \Delta$, then also $\Delta \vdash A$

and the

> *Deduction Theorem* : If $\Gamma \cup \{ A \} \vdash B$, then also $\Gamma \vdash A \to B$.

---

*Proof* :

1) $\{ A \equiv C, A \} \vdash C$ --- Equanimity

2) $\{ A \equiv C, A, B \} \vdash C$ --- Hypothesis Strengthening

3) $\{ A \equiv C, A \} \vdash B \to C$ --- Deduction Th

> 4) $A \equiv C \vdash A \to (B \to C)$ --- Deduction Th.